# Where and how to __bridge

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, core-graphics, cgpath

I need some advice on `__bridge`-ing in iOS.

Hopefully the SSCCE<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> below will explain the problem better than I can in words, but I need to know how I can convert a `void*` to an `NSMutableArray*`; which `__bridge` variation should be used (See comment in code).

Reading about the different bridges, I deduced that I would need `__bridge_transfer` but then I receive an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on `addObject:`

Ultimately, I'd like to have an array of the `CGPoints` in the `CGPath` after `CGPathApply` has been called.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void _processPathElement(void* info, const CGPathElement* element)
{
    NSMutableArray *array = (/* WHAT BRIDGE HERE */ NSMutableArray*) info;
    switch (element->type)
    {
        case kCGPathElementMoveToPoint:
        case kCGPathElementAddLineToPoint:
        {
            CGPoint point = element->points[0];
            [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        //Create path
        CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(   path, NULL, 0, 0);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 1, 0);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 1, 1);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 1);
        CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

        NSMutableArray *pathPoints = [NSMutableArray array];
        CGPathApply(path, &pathPoints, _processPathElement);

        NSLog(@"Points:%@", pathPoints);
    }
}
```

<sub>1: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)</sub>

Comment: I don't understand. I simply used `__bridge` as suggested by Xcode. And your program compiles.

Comment: Or you're looking for this, `__bridge` transfers a pointer between Objective-C and Core Foundation with no transfer of ownership.        
`__bridge_retained` or `CFBridgingRetain` casts an Objective-C pointer to a Core Foundation pointer and also transfers ownership to you.
You are responsible for calling CFRelease or a related function to relinquish ownership of the object.

`__bridge_transfer` or `CFBridgingRelease` moves a non-Objective-C pointer to Objective-C and also transfers ownership to ARC.
ARC is responsible for relinquishing ownership of the object.

Comment: @BlackFlam3 (1st comment) It's not just a case of getting the code to compile. I need the memory to be properly retained so that I have access to `pathPoints` for the `NSLog`

Comment: @BlackFlam3 (2nd comment) I read that on another site, and deduced that I would need `__bridge_transfer` but then I receive an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on `addObject:`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The documentation on the use of the bridge keyword [can be found here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). Specifically, I want to point out §3.2.4:

> `(__bridge T) op` casts the operand to the destination type T. If T is a retainable object pointer type, then op must have a non-retainable pointer type. If T is a non-retainable pointer type, then op must have a retainable object pointer type. Otherwise the cast is ill-formed. There is no transfer of ownership, and ARC inserts no retain operations.
>
> `(__bridge_retained T) op` casts the operand, which must have retainable object pointer type, to the destination type, which must be a non-retainable pointer type. ARC retains the value, subject to the usual optimizations on local values, and the recipient is responsible for balancing that +1.
>
> `(__bridge_transfer T) op` casts the operand, which must have non-retainable pointer type, to the destination type, which must be a retainable object pointer type. ARC will release the value at the end of the enclosing full-expression, subject to the usual optimizations on local values.

The pointer you're being passed in (`void*`) is a non retainable pointer type, whereas your NSMutableArray is a retainable pointer type. This rules out `__bridge_retained` straight away. So the question is, to `__bridge` or to `__bridge_transfer`?

`__bridge_transfer` is typically used when you want the Objective-C pointer from a method that returns a CF Object that has been retained. For example, CFStringCreateWithFormat will return a retained CFString, but if you want an NSString from it, you need to `__bridge_transfer` between them. This will make ARC release the object that CF retained when appropriate. For example, `NSString* str = (__bridge_transfer NSString*) CFStringCreateWithFormat(...);`

Your code isn't doing that, you don't need to meddle with the ownership. Your main method is in control of its memory management, and is simply passing a reference to a method it calls (albeit indirectly, but it's all within the scope of main). As such, you would use `__bridge`.

**But wait, when I use __bridge, my code gets memory access errors!?**

Ah, this is an issue with the code you posted, and isn't in relation to the whole bridging discussion. You need to pass a `void*` to CGApplyPath, for your processing function `_processPathElement`. What you're passing is `NSMutableArray**`.

When you recast to the `NSMutableArray*`, you're actually casting a `NSMutableArray**`. This will cause the infamous EXC_BAD_ACCESS. You need to pass the pointer itself, not a pointer to a pointer. **But**, `CGPathApply(path, pathPoints, _processPathElement)` will not work, you cannot pass off a `NSMutableArray*` as a `void*`. What you need (ironically), is a bridge. For the same reasons as before, all you need is `__bridge`. See below the code, with the correct bridges in place, and working as expected:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void _processPathElement(void* info, const CGPathElement* element)
{
    NSMutableArray *array = (__bridge NSMutableArray*) info;
    switch (element->type)
    {
        case kCGPathElementMoveToPoint:
        case kCGPathElementAddLineToPoint:
        {
            CGPoint point = element->points[0];
            [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        //Create path
        CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(   path, NULL, 0, 0);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 1, 0);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 1, 1);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 1);
        CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
        
        NSMutableArray *pathPoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        CGPathApply(path, (__bridge void*)pathPoints, _processPathElement);
        
        NSLog(@"Points:%@", pathPoints);
    }
}
```

This will print out:

```
Points:(
    "NSPoint: {0, 0}",
    "NSPoint: {1, 0}",
    "NSPoint: {1, 1}",
    "NSPoint: {0, 1}"
)
```

Comment: Thank you. =] I imagine you were writing this as I found and posted (the same) conclusion. Your answer provides a lot more information though and confirms that I stumbled across the correct solution.

Comment: Note that using the `CFBridg*` variants is often clearer (for some of us, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not actually sure why this works, but I've found the solution to be:

```
NSMutableArray *array = (__bridge NSMutableArray*) info;

//AND

CGPathApply(path, (__bridge void*)pathPoints, _processPathElement);
```

If anyone can explain why this works and confirm that there aren't (/are) any memory leaks I'd be grateful

Comment: I missed this when typing my answer (SO didn't notify me of new answers). See above for the rationale for this.